# how to fix error gui becaus imtile in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I recently learn dct and imtitile in matlab and I read a tutorial how to stitching images into one single axes,  I found imtile and so I use imtile function but the following error appears

> matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)modul3fix('pushbutton4_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>   Error while evaluating UIControl Callback.

Here is my code

```
X = handles.coba1; 
[LL,LH,HL,HH]= dwt2(X,'db1'); 
axes(handles.axes2);
out = imtile(LL,LH,HL,HH);
imshow(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say with this level of error information in the stack trace, but for sure one problem is that your call to imtile is not a valid syntax of imtile.

If you want to pass multiple in memory arguments to imtile, they have to be enclosed in a cell array.

```
out = imtile({LL,LH,HL,HH});
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imtile.html#mw_c8f524a5-cae3-4420-acaa-69664f7883f2